# Missing requirements installing software in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation, equinox

I can successfully install the software in one PC but the other PC, I get this error

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found. Software being installed: xxxxxxx() Missing requirement:
>   xxxxxx requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.pde.ui 0.0.0'
>   but it could not be found.

I can't seem to point out the difference between the two environment. 
Both are using Photon Release (4.8.0) with Java 8.